# TYPO3 - Realurl default Settings overwrite?

Tags: typo3, backend, realurl

How can I overwrite the default settings of the TYPO3 extension realurl with my own extension?

this dont work:

```
// RealUrl Config File
if (!isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['realurl']['configFile'])
|| empty(trim($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['realurl']['configFile']))
) {
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['realurl']['configFile'] = 'typo3conf/ext/xxx/Resources/Private/Hooks/realurl_conf.php';
}
```

How can I use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is that realurl is inialized and executed very early (it's the first process which needs to translate the speaking url to url parameter which decide which page and which plugin is rendered).

Your attempt to modify the assignment which is done normaly in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` could not be attached to that file as it is just an array, which gets written anew automatically every now and then.
You might add that to `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`.

But why don't you request an admin to assign the path to the config-file in your extension in the realurl EM-config by hand?

Comment: Thanks! That is the right way :) here a Example:
http://www.typo3-probleme.de/2017/08/23/typo3-ueberschreiben-von-werten-anderer-extensions-2089/